# https works for local IP address but not for local IP with application port

Tags: nginx, https, mattermost

I have Mattermost installed in my server, currently I can login to it by browsing through http://192.168.x.x:8066, I've installed a self-signed cerrtificate for this IP, but when I tried to browse it with https://192.168.x.x:8065, it failed to redirect to the Mattermost page.
Below is the configuration of my nginx.conf:

```
    server {
        listen 443 http2 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;
        listen 443;
        server_name 192.168.3.201:8066;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
           }
```

However, when I just browse the URL without port 8066 , it displays the default nginx page with no errors.
What's wrong with my nginx.conf file? I'm still new to nginx FYI.
Any suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow the example nginx configuration from the documentation [here](https://docs.mattermost.com/install/install-ubuntu-1604.html#configuring-nginx-as-a-proxy-for-mattermost-server). Start with that config file, updating `server_name` to be the domain name you want mattermost to be reachable from, and `server` to be the IP address and port on which mattermost is listening.

Once you've got that working, you can continue through the instructions to #9 which covers setting up SSL.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will try it out.